# androjena android not identifying "AS"

Tags: android, sparql, jena

attached are the jars I'm using in my android application.

[image]

And the following is the code that executes the query:

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query query = com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(
                        queryString, Syntax.syntaxARQ);
            com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution qexec = com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(
                    endpoint, query);
```

My query uses nested selects which seem to be alright, but when it comes down to:

```
(SUM(xsd:integer(?numOfMentions)) as ?sum)
```

I get an exception saying:

`

```
W/System.err(22539): com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " "as" "AS "" at line 18, column 35.
W/System.err(22539): Was expecting:
W/System.err(22539):     ")" ...
W/System.err(22539):
W/System.err(22539):    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserARQ.perform(ParserARQ.java:86)
W/System.err(22539):    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserARQ.parse(ParserARQ.java:39)
W/System.err(22539):    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.parse(QueryFactory.java:129)
W/System.err(22539):    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:72)
W/System.err(22539):    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:43)
W/System.err(22539):    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory.makeQuery(QueryExecutionFactory.java:516)
W/System.err(22539):    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory.create(QueryExecutionFactory.java:71)
W/System.err(22539):    at technion.com.testapplication.async.FetchMekorotByScoreTask.doInBackground(FetchMekorotByScoreTask.java:42)
W/System.err(22539):    at technion.com.testapplication.async.FetchMekorotByScoreTask.doInBackground(FetchMekorotByScoreTask.java:22)
W/System.err(22539):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
W/System.err(22539):    at enter code herejava.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err(22539):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err(22539):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err(22539):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err(22539):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

`

Please help

Update 1:

Attaching part of the query where I'm getting the fail.

```
   + "SELECT distinct ?source ?label ?text\n"
                + "?sums ?spanss ?labels\n"
                + "?sum ?description\n"
                + "WHERE {\n"
                + " SELECT ?source ?label ?text ?description\n"
                + " (SUM(xsd:integer(?numOfMentions)) as ?sum)\n"
                + " (group_concat(?numOfMentions;separator=\",\") as ?sums)\n"
                + " (group_concat(?spans;separator=\",\") as ?spanss)\n"
                + " (group_concat(?target_label ;separator=\",\") as ?labels)\n"
```

The error is being referred to:

```
(SUM(xsd:integer(?numOfMentions)) as ?sum
```

Update:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(?source) SAMPLE(?label) as ?label SAMPLE(?text) as ?text                
    SAMPLE(?sums) as ?sums SAMPLE(?spanss) as ?spanss SAMPLE (?labels) as ?labels           
    SAMPLE(?sum) as ?sum SAMPLE(?description) as ?description                               
    WHERE {                                                                                 
    SELECT ?source ?label ?text ?description                                                
    (SUM(xsd:integer(?numOfMentions)) as ?sum)                                              
    (group_concat(?numOfMentions;separator=",") as ?sums)                               
    (group_concat(?spans;separator=",") as ?spanss)                                     
    (group_concat(?target_label ;separator=",") as ?labels)                                 
    WHERE {                                                                                 
        SELECT ?mentions ?source ?numOfMentions ?target_label ?label ?text ?description     
        (group_concat(DISTINCT(?span);separator=",") as ?spans)                             
        WHERE                                                                               
        {                                                                                   
            {                                                                               
                values ?_var1 {prefix2:text-book-1-6-11 prefix2:text-book-1-6-16}                                   
                ?_var1 a prefix:_var1.                                                      
                ?mentions rdf:type prefix:Mention.                                          
                ?mentions prefix:target ?_var1.                                             
                ?mentions prefix:source ?source.                                                
                ?mentions prefix:numOfMentions ?numOfMentions.                                  
                ?mentions prefix:span ?span.                                                    
                ?source rdfs:label ?label.                                                  
                ?source prefix:text ?text.                                                      
                ?source prefix:book ?source_book.                                               
                ?source_book prefix:description ?description.                                   
                ?_var1 rdfs:label ?target_label }                                           
            UNION {                                                                         
                values ?container {prefix2:text-book-1-6-11 prefix2:text-book-1-6-16}                                   
                values ?types {prefix:Section prefix:_var2}                                 
                ?container a ?types.                                                        
                ?_var1 prefix:within ?container.                                                
                ?_var1 a prefix:_var1.                                                      
                ?mentions rdf:type prefix:Mention.                                              
                ?mentions prefix:target ?_var1.                                             
                ?mentions prefix:source ?source.                                                
                ?mentions prefix:numOfMentions ?numOfMentions.                                  
                ?mentions prefix:span ?span.                                                    
                ?source rdfs:label ?label.                                                  
                ?source prefix:text ?text.                                                      
                ?source prefix:book ?source_book.                                               
                ?source_book prefix:description ?description.                                   
                ?_var1 rdfs:label ?target_label                                             
            }                                                                               
            UNION {                                                                         
                values ?books {prefix2:text-book-1-6-11 prefix2:text-book-1-6-16}                                       
                values ?types { prefix:_var4 }                                          
                ?books a ?types.                                                            
                ?_var1 prefix:book ?books.                                                      
                ?_var1 a prefix:_var1.                                                      
                ?mentions rdf:type prefix:Mention.                                              
                ?mentions prefix:target ?_var1.                                             
                ?mentions prefix:source ?source.                                                
                ?mentions prefix:numOfMentions ?numOfMentions.                                  
                ?mentions prefix:span ?span.                                                    
                ?source rdfs:label ?label.                                                  
                ?source prefix:text ?text.                                                      
                ?source prefix:book ?source_book.                                               
                ?source_book prefix:description ?description.                                   
                ?_var1 rdfs:label ?target_label                                             
            }                                                                               
        }                                                                                   
        group by ?target_label ?text ?mentions ?description                                 
        ?source ?numOfMentions ?label                                                       
    }                                                                                       
    group by ?source ?label ?text ?description                                              
    }                                                                                       
    order by DESC(?sum) offset 0 limit 20
```

Comment: It would be better if you post the whole query here such that we can check whether this a parser error or a syntax error in your query.

Comment: I ran the query online and it seemed to work fine, it just doesn't work on Android for some reason. I can't really post the whole query as it's private property of a client. I'm attaching the beginning of the query to the original post

Comment: Are the libs I'm using sufficient for such queries?

Comment: I don't know, the Android Jena libs are based on a quite old version of Apache Jena. The query parser might be not SPARQL 1.1 compliant or there might be a bug when parsing the sub-SELECT. Some questions: 1) Does it work without the `SUM`, i.e. does the `GROUP_CONCAT` which is another aggregate function work? 2.) is it necessary to cast `?numOfMentions` to an integer? What kind of datatype is it? 3.) What happens if you use a different parser syntax, i.e. `QueryFactory.create(
                        queryString, Syntax.syntaxSPARQL_11)` to get the proper SPARQL 1.1 parser

Comment: When I use SPARQL_11 it says that it's not supported yet. Do you know by any chance where I can get updated androjena jars for that/ a way to make it work on android? As I'm now working with these libs and they seem to suffice when it comes down to simple queries. Whereas, more complex ones it fails.

Comment: Now that I read your comment, are you really using androjena?! This is a **six years old** project, that's much before SPARQL 1.1, and to be honest, I'd never use such an old framework which is also not maintained anymore. You can't really consider using this for production...why would fix bugs or give support?

Comment: There is another open source project, which is also 3 years old but should at least cover SPARQL 1.1 properly: https://github.com/sbrunk/jena-android But again, it's probably not maintained anymore given the fact that latest Apache Jena version is 3.6.0 and this is based on 2.13.0 Anyways, I'd try to use this project first. And if it doesn't work, you should ask on the Jena mailing list whether somebody knows a newer Android fork of Jena.

Comment: Yes, I've tried the jena-android one with little success. If you know some REST API implementation for querying sparql via an endpoint that would be great too.

Comment: What means "little success"? The query should be parsable by Jena 2.13.0 . Why REST API? You can query most of the triple stores via HTTP protocol. And as I already asked, does a more simple query with just a single aggregate function work? I can't believe that the snippet you've can't be parsed.

Comment: It can be parsed, it is when I'm doing it online. But when I use android it can't be parsed correctly. I do think it's a problem with the jena android libraries being old. It's frustrating that there's no community for it in android at all. and about the rest, I was actually asking if you know some open source implementation for android for querying a sparql endpoint with http.

Comment: To be honest, I cannot help you without seeing the query. The problem can't be in the SUM. I checked out jena-android and tried with a minimized query:

Comment: `String s = "prefix : <http://ex.org/test/> prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>" +
                "SELECT distinct ?source\n"
                + "?sums\n"
                + "?sum\n"
                + "WHERE {\n"
                + " SELECT ?source\n"
                + " (SUM(xsd:integer(?numOfMentions)) as ?sum)\n"
                + " (group_concat(?numOfMentions;separator=\",\") as ?sums)\n"
                + "WHERE {?s :p ?numOfMentions} GROUP BY ?source" +
                "}";
        QueryFactory.create(s);` It works as expected.

Comment: Jena 2.13.0 is able to parse full SPARQL 1.1, thus, there **must** be some syntax error in your query. Please try wrap the sub-SELECT into `{` and `}` if you have other triple patterns after the query. If it's a problem to show the real query, why not anonymizing it? You can replace each var name by `v_1, ..., v_n`.

Comment: Do you have a sample jena-android project you can link me to ?

Comment: No, I just tested it in the `jena-arq` module within the `jena-android` project with a dummy class in a new Java source folder `src/main/java`. All I wanted to know is whether the used Jena version is able to parse those queries and it did. That's why I don't understand why your query should not be parsable. And as I said, you can also post the whole query with replaced anonym variables names if your client doesn't want to have the original query being online.

Comment: I updated, would love if you could go over it.

Comment: Done. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the help,
but it didn't help either.

At the end I managed to query my remote service endpoint by using androjena, and the following:

```
QueryEngineHTTP queryEngineHTTP = new QueryEngineHTTP(Queries.ENDPOINT, queryString);
queryEngineHTTP.execSelect()
ResultSet resultSet = queryEngineHTTP.execSelect();
while (resultSet.hasNext()) {
   QuerySolution rb = resultSet.nextSolution();
   // parse rb here.
}
```

This way I managed to get rid of the parser and just get post results and parse them myself.

I hope this helps people in the future who want to use androjena.

Answer (score 0):

The query has several problems:

1. remove the outer `DISTINCT` around `?source` variable. that's illegal and is also not necessary as the inner query grouped by it.
2. you have to `GROUP BY` the `?source` variable once you're using aggregate functions like `SAMPLE`
3. you did it in the inner queries, but not in the outer: wrap those `... AS ...` in `(` and `)`. for example, `SAMPLE(?label) as ?label` must be `(SAMPLE(?label) as ?label)`
4. assignment of a variable name with a name that has already been used doesn't work. for example, `(SAMPLE(?label) as ?label)` could be `(SAMPLE(?label) as ?label_)` indeed, you should rename the names of the inner variables in order to get the "good" var names in the final result.

The parsable version of your query:

```sql
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX  prefix: <http://...>
PREFIX  prefix2: <http://...>

SELECT  ?source (SAMPLE(?label_) AS ?label) (SAMPLE(?text_) AS ?text) (SAMPLE(?sums_) AS ?sums) (SAMPLE(?spanss_) AS ?spanss) (SAMPLE(?labels_) AS ?labels) (SAMPLE(?sum_) AS ?sum) (SAMPLE(?description_) AS ?description)
WHERE
  { SELECT  ?source (?label AS ?label_) (?text AS ?text_) (?description AS ?description_) (SUM(xsd:integer(?numOfMentions)) AS ?sum_) (GROUP_CONCAT(?numOfMentions ; separator=',') AS ?sums_) (GROUP_CONCAT(?spans ; separator=',') AS ?spanss_) (GROUP_CONCAT(?target_label ; separator=',') AS ?labels_)
    WHERE
      { SELECT  ?mentions ?source ?numOfMentions ?target_label ?label ?text ?description (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?span ; separator=',') AS ?spans)
        WHERE
          {   { VALUES ?_var1 { prefix2:text-book-1-6-11 prefix2:text-book-1-6-16 }
                ?_var1    rdf:type              prefix2:_var1 .
                ?mentions  rdf:type             prefix2:Mention ;
                          prefix2:target        ?_var1 ;
                          prefix2:source        ?source ;
                          prefix2:numOfMentions  ?numOfMentions ;
                          prefix2:span          ?span .
                ?source   rdfs:label            ?label ;
                          prefix2:text          ?text ;
                          prefix2:book          ?source_book .
                ?source_book  prefix2:description  ?description .
                ?_var1    rdfs:label            ?target_label
              }
            UNION
              { VALUES ?container { prefix2:text-book-1-6-11 prefix2:text-book-1-6-16 }
                VALUES ?types { prefix2:Section prefix2:_var2 }
                ?container  rdf:type            ?types .
                ?_var1    prefix2:within        ?container ;
                          rdf:type              prefix2:_var1 .
                ?mentions  rdf:type             prefix2:Mention ;
                          prefix2:target        ?_var1 ;
                          prefix2:source        ?source ;
                          prefix2:numOfMentions  ?numOfMentions ;
                          prefix2:span          ?span .
                ?source   rdfs:label            ?label ;
                          prefix2:text          ?text ;
                          prefix2:book          ?source_book .
                ?source_book  prefix2:description  ?description .
                ?_var1    rdfs:label            ?target_label
              }
            UNION
              { VALUES ?books { prefix2:text-book-1-6-11 prefix2:text-book-1-6-16 }
                VALUES ?types { prefix2:_var4 }
                ?books    rdf:type              ?types .
                ?_var1    prefix2:book          ?books ;
                          rdf:type              prefix2:_var1 .
                ?mentions  rdf:type             prefix2:Mention ;
                          prefix2:target        ?_var1 ;
                          prefix2:source        ?source ;
                          prefix2:numOfMentions  ?numOfMentions ;
                          prefix2:span          ?span .
                ?source   rdfs:label            ?label ;
                          prefix2:text          ?text ;
                          prefix2:book          ?source_book .
                ?source_book  prefix2:description  ?description .
                ?_var1    rdfs:label            ?target_label
              }
          }
        GROUP BY ?target_label ?text ?mentions ?description ?source ?numOfMentions ?label
      }
    GROUP BY ?source ?label ?text ?description
  }
GROUP BY ?source
ORDER BY DESC(?sum)
OFFSET  0
LIMIT   20
```